# Ubuntu 11.10 with gnome shell - suspend wake up sound

Tags: audio, gnome-shell

I would like to be able to enable some sound file to play whenever I suspend and wake up my netbook (MSI Wind u100) but I can't found a way to do this in gnome shell.

I'm using PinguyOS 11.10, which is Ubuntu 11.10 based distro.

The idea is to make my netbook to basically greet me every time I wake up from suspend. Something like "Welcome back, Master" announced by a sexy robotic voice.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting a script in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/`. Scripts in this folder gets launched on resume from sleep.

The file could look something like this

```
#!/bin/sh
mplayer '/path/to/file/music.mp3'
```

Don't forget to run the command `chmod +x yourscriptfilename` so that the file is executable.

Comment: The script itself is working great and is executable, however it doesn't seem to work after a suspend. I've put `sleep 5` to delay mplayer in case script loads faster than pulseaudio but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have "libcanberra" installed? I am running Fedora18--gnome, and currently I have an "autostart" script for the login sound that executes the following command:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/canberra-gtk-play -f /home/user/.local/share/sounds/.../desktop-login.ogg
```

Try this, if you want:

1. Place the sound-file (if it's not already) in `/usr/share/sounds`
2. Create a script, as already suggested in `/etc/pm/sleep.d` containing something like

   #!/bin/sh
       /usr/bin/canberra-gtk-play -f /path/to/sound/file

As I said, my login-sound file is a simple desktop-entry in the `~/.config/autostart` directory with the aforementioned "Exec=..." line along with everything else that goes in a Desktop Entry, of course.  Best of luck